# Nuget package added but no reference

Tags: logging, nuget, visual-studio-2017, enterprise-library

I tried to google my problem, but without success. I created new Class Library (.NET Standard) project in Visual Studio 2017. I added EnterpriseLibrary.Logging package via NPM, it is displayed in Dependencies, but I am not able to use anythink from that package in my class. 
When I was doing it in similar way in VS 2015, everythink works OK. 
Does anyone know how can I make this working in VS 2017? My project looks like this. I also tried it with different package but with same result.

[Visual studio project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXtwQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone know how can I make this working in VS 2017?

That because you are install the .NET framework library to the .NET Standard project. **This package may not fully compatible with your project**. You can get this warning after install this package:

[image]

So you could not install it for .NET Standard project, you can use this package for .Net framework project, otherwise we need to wait for the author of this package to update this package to compatible with .NET Standard.

Besides, you can notice that the last update date of this package is `Friday, April 26, 2013 (4/26/2013)`, which need to be updated.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't. I try to create Class library as .NET standard project, and also as a .NET framework project, and result is still the same. I also tried to create class library with older version of .Net framework (4.5.2), but the same problem

Comment: @user3899265,Could not understand what you said "I try to create Class library as .NET standard project, and also as a .NET framework project, and result is still the same." Do you mean that you have created a nuget package, which have multiple .NET framework .NET standard and .NET framework?

Comment: And "I also tried to create class library with older version of .Net framework (4.5.2), but the same problem" You still install the .NET framework package to .NET Standard project, you will get the same result. You need to create .NET Standard class library with .NET Standard 1.6 or 2.0, then install this library to .NET Standard project. To use the package `EnterpriseLibrary.Logging`, please create a .NET framework project and install it.